# lsp-mode Golang build tags

Tags: customize, lsp-mode

I am using lsp-mode with Gopls as my coding environment. But I have one file with

```golang
// +build tagthis
```

at beginning of the file. Then my emacs lsp-mode cannot work well in this file. How can I change custom of go build flag for letting lsp-mode works well in this file?

I have make

```
(setq 
   lsp-go-build-flags (vector "tagthis")
   )
```

in my configuration. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the solution. Just change `lsp-go-env` with

```
(setq 
   lsp-go-env '((GOFLAGS . "-tags=tagthis"))
   )
```

make it works.